# How to use angular linker to solve my JIT compilation time error and add rules inside my webpack

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, babel-loader

I have JIT compilation time error.
I debugged and the reason for that is external library that is having `"compilationMode": "partial"` setted in `angularCompilerOptions`

You can check the library here

https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/blob/master/src/ng-option-highlight/tsconfig.lib.json

I followed the angular documenation for this thing
https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries#consuming-partial-ivy-code-outside-the-angular-cli

and for such case they say we need to use angular linker and babel loader

My angular version is 12 and my package.json looks like this

```
{
  "name": "xecm",
  "version": "3.7.0-SNAPSHOT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port 4200",
    "build:prod": "npm run lint && ng build --configuration production && npm run copy-url-handlers",
    "build:debug": "npm run build:prod -- --source-map",
    "build:int": "ng build --configuration production --optimization=false && npm run copy-url-handlers",
    "bundle-report": "ng build --configuration production --stats-json && webpack-bundle-analyzer target/dist/stats-es5.json",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint xecm",
    "lint:watch": "nodemon --exec \"npm run lint || exit 1\" --ext ts",
    "lint:fix": "npm run lint -- --fix",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "copy-url-handlers": "cpr ./src/WEB-INF ./target/dist/WEB-INF"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.16",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.16",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.16",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.16",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.16",
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^10.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.5.3",
    "bootstrap.native": "3.0.13",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "html-lint": "^2.4.2",
    "moment": "2.29.1",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.4.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "~6.5.2",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "xcomponent-angular": "^3.0.0-rc.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "10.0.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "12.2.16",
    "@angular/cli": "12.2.16",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "12.2.16",
    "@angular/language-service": "12.2.16",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "14.11.8",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "cpr": "3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "6.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "9.0.0",
    "tslint": "6.1.3",
    "typescript": "4.3.5",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "3.9.0",
    "dotenv": "~8.2.0"
  },
  "proxy": {
    "profiles": {
      "vntils13": [
        {
          "authorization": {
            "username": "DEV_VN_USERNAME",
            "password": "DEV_VN_PASSWORD"
          },
          "context": [
            "/xecm-web",
            "/xframework-saas-web/rest",
            "/xframework-security-web/rest",
            "/xframework-event-web/rest",
            "/xframework-objectstore-web/rest"
          ],
          "target": {
            "protocol": "https",
            "hostname": "192.168.73.44",
            "port": "8443"
          }
        }
      ],
      "localhost": [
        {
          "authorization": {
            "username": "DEV_VN_USERNAME",
            "password": "DEV_VN_PASSWORD"
          },
          "context": [
            "/xecm-web",
            "/xframework-saas-web/rest",
            "/xframework-security-web/rest",
            "/xframework-event-web/rest",
            "/xframework-objectstore-web/rest"
          ],
          "target": {
            "protocol": "https",
            "hostname": "localhost",
            "port": "8443"
          }
        }
      ],
      "dev-sk": [
        {
          "authorization": {
            "username": "DEV_SK_USERNAME",
            "password": "DEV_SK_PASSWORD"
          },
          "context": [
            "/xecm-web",
            "/xframework-saas-web/rest",
            "/xframework-security-web/rest",
            "/xframework-event-web/rest",
            "/xframework-objectstore-web/rest"
          ],
          "target": {
            "protocol": "https",
            "hostname": "localhost",
            "port": "9543"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://npm.external.io/npm-private/"
  }
}
```

So now if I add the code according to their example inside my `extra-webpack.config.js` file

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
const linkerPlugin = require("@angular/compiler-cli/linker/babel");

module.exports = {
    /**
     * Remove all unused MomentJS locales
     * The problem is described in this article
     * https://medium.jonasbandi.net/angular-cli-and-moment-js-a-recipe-for-disaster-and-how-to-fix-it-163a79180173
     */
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[/\\]locale$/, /de|en|fr|it/),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                include: /node_modules/,
                test: /\.mjs$/,
                type: 'javascript/auto'
            }
        ]
    },
    optimization: {
        minimize: true,
        minimizer: [
          new TerserPlugin({
            terserOptions: {
              ecma: undefined,
              parse: {},
              compress: {},
              mangle: true, // Note `mangle.properties` is `false` by default.
              module: false,
              // Deprecated
              output: null,
              format: null,
              toplevel: false,
              nameCache: null,
              ie8: false,
              keep_classnames: undefined,
              keep_fnames: false,
              safari10: false,
            },
          }),
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            ngDevMode: true,
        })
    ],
    rules: [
        {
          test: /\.m?js$/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              plugins: [linkerPlugin],
              compact: false,
              cacheDirectory: true,
            }
          }
        }
    ]
}
```

NOTE: I add `rules` as on the documentation I get error

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration has an unknown property 'rules'. These properties are valid:
   object { amd?, bail?, cache?, context?, dependencies?, devServer?, devtool?, entry?, externals?, infrastructureLogging?, loader?, mode?, module?, name?, node?, optimization?, output?, parallelism?, performance?, plugins?, profile?, recordsInputPath?, recordsOutputPath?, recordsPath?, resolve?, resolveLoader?, serve?, stats?, target?, watch?, watchOptions? }
   For typos: please correct them.
   For loader options: webpack >= v2.0.0 no longer allows custom properties in configuration.
     Loaders should be updated to allow passing options via loader options in module.rules.
     Until loaders are updated one can use the LoaderOptionsPlugin to pass these options to the loader:
     plugins: [
       new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
         // test: /\.xxx$/, // may apply this only for some modules
         options: {
           rules: …
         }
       })
     ]
```

what should I include instead rules here ? When I search on webpack documentation there is `rules` thing but on my side it does not work.

As I know angular 12 is using outof the box webpack version 5.

Previously I had angular 12 and I migrated to angular 12. Is it maked automatically or not ?
How can i check which version of webpack is used inside my angular project
and fix my error so I can link the library through angular and my compilation error will be gone

Answer (score 0):

So because I have older version of webpack I need to use following syntax

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
const linkerPlugin = require("@angular/compiler-cli/linker/babel");

module.exports = {
    /**
     * Remove all unused MomentJS locales
     * The problem is described in this article
     * https://medium.jonasbandi.net/angular-cli-and-moment-js-a-recipe-for-disaster-and-how-to-fix-it-163a79180173
     */
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[/\\]locale$/, /de|en|fr|it/),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                include: /node_modules/,
                test: /\.mjs$/,
                type: 'javascript/auto'
            }
        ]
    },
    optimization: {
        minimize: true,
        minimizer: [
          new TerserPlugin({
            terserOptions: {
              ecma: undefined,
              parse: {},
              compress: {},
              mangle: true, // Note `mangle.properties` is `false` by default.
              module: false,
              // Deprecated
              output: null,
              format: null,
              toplevel: false,
              nameCache: null,
              ie8: false,
              keep_classnames: undefined,
              keep_fnames: false,
              safari10: false,
            },
          }),
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            ngDevMode: true,
        }),
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            options: {
                rules: [
                    {
                      test: /.*\.js$/,
                      include: /node_modules\/@ng-select/,
                      use: {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                          configFile: false,
                          plugins: [linkerPlugin],
                        }
                      }
                    }
                ]
            }
        })
    ],
}
```

So

```
new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({ inside plugins
```

instead of rules directly